# When I download a file from my React app it cannot be read because of wrong encoding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

I have a backend Java application and a frontend React app. In my frontend project, on one of my route, I have this function for downloading a file:

```js
const onDownload = () => {
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `http://localhost:8080/files/download/${id}`,
            validateStatus: () => true,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
        }).then(resp => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([resp.data]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.download = file.filename;

            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
        });
    };
```

However, if I download a file from my React app, for example an image, it won't open. I tried to open it in notepad and discovered that this file contains question marks. As I understood, it means that my file is in wrong encoding.

But if I download the same file directly from my server's endpoint, for example using Postman, it opens in right encoding.

How to solve this? Should I convert my data in React app in right encoding?

I tried to somehow convert my response data to utf-8 encoding but it didn't work.

Comment: You can pass ``responseType: "blob"`` to the Axios request. Then `URL.createObjectURL(resp.data)` when handling the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue. What I did is just replaced axios request to fetch request like that:

```js
const myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append('Authorization', "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"));
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080/files/download/${id}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: myHeaders
        }).then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => {
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = url;
                a.download = file.filename;
                a.click();
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            });
```